# Setting text to a view from another XML

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I have the `activity_main.xml` and `popup_window.xml`.

I have this code and I want to set text to a `TextView` from the `popup_window.xml`:

```
    TextView quadEqu = (TextView) ctx.findViewById(R.id.quadEqu);

    String form = "Ax^2+Bx+C";
    if (popA >= 0)
        form.replace("A", "" + popA);
    else
        form.replace("A", "(-" + popA + ")");
    if (popB >= 0)
        form.replace("B", "" + popB);
    else
        form.replace("B", "(-" + popB + ")");
    if (popC >= 0)
        form.replace("C", "" + popC);
    else
        form.replace("C", "(-" + popC + ")");

    //quadEqu.setText(form);
```

It's inside a private with 4 args (final Activity ctx, double popA, double popB, double popC).
The commented line is the problematic want...

Comment: you need to inflate the layout and `findViewById` looks for a view with the current inflated layout. so i guess you have NullPointerException at `TextView quadEqu = (TextView) ctx.findViewById(R.id.quadEqu);`. How do you inflate `popup_window.xml` in `activity_main.xml`? and post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing activity pass dialog that is inflating your popup_window.xml and call findViewById on that dialog object.

Comment: May you explain it programmatically?